# Average of Column

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
Meal         Item            Cost
Breakfast    Oatmeal          5
Breakfast    Omelette         7
Lunch        Clam Chowder    10
Lunch        Steak           12
Lunch        Burger          9
Dinner       Clam Chowder    10
Dinner       Steak           12
Dinner       Burger          9
Dessert      Apple Pie       6
Dessert      Chocolate Cake  5
```

I need to show in SQL query Meal, Item, and average_meal_cost. Average meal cost gives an overall average cost of all items connected with a meal. For example, the first 2 rows would show 6 in the average column.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `avg()` as a window function:

```
select t.*, avg(cost * 1.0) over (partition by meal) as avg_meal_cost
from t;
```

The `* 1.0` is because some databases calculate the average of integers as an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.